# Optimization problem for an undefined function in R

Tags: r, optimization, argmax

Suppose we have an unknown function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and a dataset of m rows and (n+1) columns of function values for some argument values $(x_{1,m}, x_{2,m},...,x_{n,m}, y_m)$, where m = 1,...,1000 and $y_{m} = f(x_{1,m}, x_{2,m},...,x_{n,m})$.

Given this data, how to estimate argument values that maximize $f$? It's a derivative-free optimization problem, but I'm looking for the simplest solutions available in R.

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: Use `which.max(y)` to choose the row with the largest value.  Without more assumptions about `f`, or the ability to evaluate it, you probably can't do any better.